# SwiftUI contextmenu wrong location

Tags: swiftui, contextmenu

I am trying to add a contextmenu to images I display, but when I longpress, the contextmenu opens in a wrong location (see image)

The code I use is:

```
ForEach(self.document.instruments) { instrument in
    Image(instrument.text)
        .resizable()
        .frame(width: 140, height: 70)
        .position(self.position(for: instrument, in: geometry.size))
        .gesture(self.singleTapForSelection(for: instrument))
        .gesture(self.dragSelectionInstrument(for: instrument))
        .shadow(color: self.isInstrumentSelected(instrument) ? .blue : .clear, radius: 10 * self.zoomScale(for: instrument))
        .contextMenu {
            Button {
                print("Deleted selected")
            } label: {
                Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
            }
        }
}
```

[image: Where the context menu is and where it should be]

**Update of issue**

The issue I still face (as my last comment), is that when I drag an image, there seems to be a delay, as the image remains on its position for a short moment and then moves to the dragged position. I already found out that when I have the contextMenu in the code, the delay dragging happens, when commented out, it works fine.

This is the code I have:

```
ForEach(self.document.instruments) { instrument in
    Image(instrument.text)
        .resizable()
        .frame(width: 140, height: 70)
        .contextMenu {
            Button {
                print("Deleted selected")
            } label: {
                Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
            }
        }
        .position(self.position(for: instrument, in: geometry.size))
        .shadow(color: self.isInstrumentSelected(instrument) ? .blue : .clear, radius: 10 * self.zoomScale(for: instrument))
        .gesture(self.singleTapForSelection(for: instrument))
        .gesture(self.dragSelectionInstrument(for: instrument))
}
```

I even tried moving the gestures above the contextmenu, but didn't work.

Please help

**Latest Update**

Nm, it was only on the simulator, on my physical iPad it works fine

Comment: Does it work better if you put the `.contextMenu` modifier before the `.position` modifier?

Comment: @robmayoff awesome that did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your code applies the `contextMenu` modifier after the `position` modifier.

Let's consider this slightly modified example:

```
ZStack {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        ForEach(self.document.instruments, id: \.id) { instrument in
            Image(instrument.text)
                .frame(width: 140, height: 70)
                .position(self.position(for: instrument, in: geometry.size))
                .contextMenu { ... }
        }
    }
}
```

In the SwiftUI layout system, a parent view is responsible for assigning positions to its child views. A view modifier acts as the parent of the view it modifies. So in the example code:

- `ZStack` is the parent of `GeometryReader`.
- `GeometryReader` is the parent of `ForEach`.
- `ForEach` is the parent of `contextMenu`.
- `contextMenu` is the parent of `position`.
- `position` is the parent of `frame`.
- `frame` is the parent of `Image`.
- `Image` is not a parent. It has no children.

(Sometimes the parent is called the “superview” and the child is called the “subview”.)

When `contextMenu` needs to know where to draw the menu on the screen, it looks at the position given to it by its parent, the `ForEach`, which gets it from the `GeometryReader`, which gets it from the `ZStack`.

When `Image` needs to know where to draw its pixels on the screen, it looks at the position given to it by its parent, which is the `frame` modifier, and the `frame` modifier gets the position from the `position` modifier, and the `position` modifier modifies the position given to it by the `contextMenu`.

This means that the `position` modifier does **not** affect where the `contextMenu` draws the menu.

Now let's rearrange the code so `contextMenu` is the child of `position`:

```
ZStack {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        ForEach(self.document.instruments, id: \.id) { instrument in
            Image(instrument.text)
                .frame(width: 140, height: 70)
                .contextMenu { ... }
                .position(self.position(for: instrument, in: geometry.size))
        }
    }
}
```

Now the `contextMenu` gets its position from the `position` modifier, which modifies the position given to it by the `ForEach`. So in this scenario, the `position` modifier **does** affect the where the `contextMenu` draws the menu.

Comment: Thanks, that I got from your previous comment

Comment: I noticed there is a "delay" when I drag the image, when I drag it, for a brief moment it shows the image on its original position, while the dragged image is on a different location. Then it jumps to the new location. This has something to do with the contextmenu, as when I comment out the contextmenu, it works fine.

Comment: Nm, it was only on the simulator, on my physical iPad it works fine